# How does the Vishnuswami sect differ from the Pushtimarg sect in philosophies and practices?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism, sects, pushti-marga

It is said Vishnu taught Vaishnavism to his prime devotees: Lord Shiva, Mother Lakshmi, the four Kumaras and Lord Brahma. These devotees then in turn taught mankind the principles of Vishnu bhakti. As a result there are 4 main divisions in Vaishnavism: Sri Sampradaya originating from Mother Lakshmi, Rudra Sampradaya originating from Lord Shiva, Nimbarka Sampradaya formed by the four Kumaras and the Brahma Sampradaya from Lord Brahma. Each of these divisions have their own subdivisions. Now coming to the Rudra Sampradaya, it is subdivided into 2 sects:- The common and well known Pushtimarg sect, followers of Vallabhacharya and the less known Vishnuswami sect. Now my question is that how does the Vishnuswami sect differ from Pushtimarg sect in philosophies and practices?

Comment: "It is said Vishnu taught Vaishnavism to his prime devotees: Lord Shiva, Mother Lakshmi, the four Kumaras and Lord Brahma. These devotees then in turn taught mankind the principles of Vishnu bhakti." - Where it is said?

Comment: I think after Vishnuswami, Vallabhacharya was appointed as Acharya of Rudra sect. Then Vallabhacharya founded pushtimarg. Both sects are same.

Comment: Acc. to wiki both sects are different as you said. But both the acharyas are associated with Shuddhadvaita only. I guess, I read somewhere that Vishnuswami worshiped Lord Vishnu as supreme where as Vallabhacharya worshiped Lord Krishna.

Comment: Both are same..Have you done Google search about the same ?